# AVD hardware buttons not enabled (HAXM) on API 10

Tags: android, android-emulator

With reference to the application of a custom device definitions in AVD Manager (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100251/avd-hardware-buttons-not-enabled/15100427#15100427)), can I get this working on HAXM emulator running API level 10 (2.3.3)?

I am currently using generic device definition "Nexus 4" to allow me to select the CPU/ABI "Intel Atom (x86)" image for API 10.  As soon as I a clone a new device definition ("Nexus 4 Custom") and try to apply it, the CPI/ABI drop-down becomes disabled.

I need to test hardware 'back' button behaviour on this API.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Don't try to edit an existing AVM with your new device definition. Just create a new one.