# Emulator 4.4 android don't show options menu

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-4.4-kitkat

I've updated my sdk to the latest version (android 4.4) and I started the emulator, but now I can't click on Menu, and my OptionsMenu doen't show.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: By menu do you mean the hard buttons on the emulator or the overflow button on the top right of the screen? Hard Button on the emulator are not supported on version 3.0 and up i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer at:

[AVD hardware buttons not enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100251/)

Moreover New Phones like Nexus4 menu option key does not appear (it should appear near back key on bottom of screen)

Refer

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html