# How to open RN menu in Android Emulator?

Tags: android-emulator, react-native

In genymotion, I usually press the hardware menu button to activate the react-native menu. But in Android Emulator I can't find any such button:

[image: button bar]

Comment: Check if you have enabled hardware buttons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15100251/avd-hardware-buttons-not-enabled

Comment: there is something with that skin that hide that options i think, i remember i tried and the only way i found was by sending the input event with adb
'adb shell input keyevent 82' http://stackoverflow.com/a/8483797/1868008 not very convenient though